# Create a simple form in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

All I need to do is have a form that does this:

```
User enters postcode in text box
Upon submit user is redirected to mysite.com/[user postcode]
```

That's it! I know validation etc. would be desirable as well, but I just need to get this working for now. I don't mind if it's harcoded or utilises the Drupal form API (actually I'd prefer the former!).

I know this is dead simple, but unfortunately I'm coming from a front-end background and have a bit to learn about this sort of thing :(

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a custom module and write a routing file inside the module. Register your form inside src/Form folder. Inside the formname.php file implement a class which extends drupal's form base.This link has all the  [form api details.](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api)